# How to Check if a SubView was Tapped inside a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, subview

Is it possible to know if I successfully tapped on a SubView inside a `UIView` which is inside a `UIScrollView` during the hit test method?

`UIScrollView->UIView->SubView`

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Do something
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A little more context would be good.

Your subview will will be the view handling the touch as long as it has `userInteractionEnabled` set to `YES` and is visible, i.e. not hidden and alpha greater than or equal to `0.01`.

I'm not sure why you want to override `hitTest:withEvent:`, but if you're sure that's what you want to to do, then you should be able to solve your problem with `pointInside:withEvent:`.

Comment: My `userInteractionEnabled` is already set to `YES`. What I want to do is to check if the user tapped on an `UIImageView` so I can stop the scrolling if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Put your image view inside a UIButton or add a gesture recognizer to it

Comment: @0xdeadfa11 `UIImageView` has `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO` by default. So forgetting to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` for `UIImageView`s is a common mistake. Anyway, I think this answer will solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4629821/310121

Comment: Yep, that would help but I have many `UIImageView`s and I want to work on a particular `UIImageView`.  Lets say I solve the problem, the `UIScrollView` won't scroll now when tapped on the `UIImageView` but in some point I still want it to scroll (lets say the user holds his finger on the screen then swipes). 

And is it possible to know the direction of swipe on `hitTest:withEvent:`? Lets say, swiping diagonally upward will disable scrolling else the scroll is enabled. 

Thanks!