# present a storyboard UIViewController from a UIScrollView subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to present a view controller from a UIScrollView subview.
I've tried using AppDelegate window.rootViewController presentViewController: but that gives me the "view is not in the hierarchy!" error.
I want to avoid using addSubview because that breaks MVC and seems to remove the controller's functionality (buttons stop working). 
When I use the expected presentViewController method, I get "No visible @interface for "InititalScrollViewSubview" declares the selector "presentViewController:animated:completion:", which I think means that my initialScrollViewSubview is trying to use presentViewController but presentViewController has to come from a UIViewController. UIScrollView is without the presentViewController method.

My code is something like:

```
-(void)setupTouchIDButtonTapped: (id)sender {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"newViewController" bundle:nil];
    NewViewController *myNewViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNewVC"];
```

//First thing I tried:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:NewViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

//second thing I tried

```
[self addSubview:NewViewController.view];
```

//third thing I tried:

```
[self presentViewController:NewViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

The InitialScrollViewSubview has to remain the way it is. Ideally, I'd refactor everything so the InitialScrollViewSubview is another UIViewController but I work for a huge company and the app is way too large :)
Any advice is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to 'embed' a view controller's view within your scrollview then you dont present the view controller. You instantiate it and then add it's view to the view hierarchy.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"newViewController" bundle:nil];
    NewViewController *myNewViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNewVC"];

[scrollView addSubview:NewViewController.view];
```

You will also need to setup the size/frame of the view or setup autolayout constraints so that the view controller is correctly sized.

Comment: Thanks! 
I tried that, using [self addSubview:NewViewController.vew];
The view appears but all my buttons stop working. Is this because it loses the "controller" functionality because it's now just apart of the scrollView view?

Comment: The scrollview would likely be the primary view registered to receive events, try to enable userInteractionenabled on the viewcontroller.view. you can also try the tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629499/how-to-steal-touches-from-uiscrollview

Comment: This is likely the solution you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649639/uibutton-does-not-work-when-it-in-uiscrollview

Answer (score 0):

Try this

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"newViewController" bundle:nil];

```
NewViewController *myNewViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNewVC"];
```

AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

UINavigationController * rootNvc = delegate.window.rootViewController ;

[rootNvc pushViewController:NewViewController animated:YES];